# Assigning a value to Label.Text eventually results in StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, multithreading, stack-overflow

I am building a dashboard style Windowsform, I have various timers to update the controls on the form, and all are working great, except one, the only one I am using a Label Control as the indicator.

I have various System.Timers to update the data of the indicators all stored in classes that run ever 5 minutes or so, then another timer set to update the GUI that runs every second.  For some reason this code:

```
l_LastShipment.Text = GlobalStatic.fulfillmentInd.Caption;
```

within the GUI Update eventually errors in a StackOverflowException, usually after a couple of hours.  fulfillmentInd.Caption is just a string variable in the class, and at the time of the error contains the proper data (Usually "0:01" or something similar).

Originally the GUI Timer was a System.Timer but was afraid the Invoke to update the Label was were the error was coming from, so switched the GUI timer to a Windows.Forms.Timer so it didn't require the Invoke, yet the error still occurs.

There is no recursion taking place, and I even monitored the time it takes the Update GUI function to run and it is always less than 1/10th of a second, even when the error occurs.

Here is the trimmed GUI Refresh function:

```
        private void guiHandleTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Refresh the Indicators

        //Stopwatch
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        //Compact indicator
        if (GlobalStatic.compactInd.Changed())
        {
            pb_Compact.Value = GlobalStatic.compactInd.value;
            pb_Compact.Caption = GlobalStatic.compactInd.Caption;
            pb_CompactTT.SetToolTip(pb_Compact, GlobalStatic.compactInd.tooltip);
            GlobalStatic.compactInd.Reset();
        }


        //
        //Other Indicators removed for readability
        //

        //Fulfillment Indicator
        if (GlobalStatic.fulfillmentInd.Changed())
        {
            if (GlobalStatic.fulfillmentInd.value <= 59)
            {
                //Within an Hour, Light Yellow
                p_fulfillment.BackColor = Color.LightYellow;

            }
            else if (GlobalStatic.fulfillmentInd.value <= 300)
            {
                //Between an hour and 5 hours, Change to Green
                p_fulfillment.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                //Over 5 hours old, Grey
                p_fulfillment.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            }
            l_LastShipment.Text = GlobalStatic.fulfillmentInd.Caption;     <-------This is the line that generates the StackOverflow ----->
            ToolTip test = new ToolTip();
            test.SetToolTip(p_fulfillment, GlobalStatic.fulfillmentInd.tooltip);
            test.SetToolTip(l_LastShipment, GlobalStatic.fulfillmentInd.tooltip);
            GlobalStatic.fulfillmentInd.Reset();
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan t = stopwatch.Elapsed;
        if(TimeSpan.Compare(largestTime,t)==-1)
        {
            //largestTime is shorter than t, change largestTime
            largestTime = t;
        }
        T_GUI.Text = largestTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\:fff");
    }
```

Here is the Timer Setup, called during Form Load, the only place that GUIHandleTimer is mentioned in code:

```
            //GUI Refresh Timer
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer guiTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        guiTimer.Interval = 1000;
        guiTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(guiHandleTimer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the StackOverflow.  The reason it took so long for me to figure it out and finally to ask here, is that Visual Studio was always code-breaking on the Label.Text line highlighted in my original question.  Unfortunately, that was not the line causing the StackOverflow, it was the next line that was causing it.

```
ToolTip test = new ToolTip();
```

For some reason I didn't move that New ToolTip() out of the Handler after I was done fixing my ToolTips, so I was overloading new ToolTips into the Stack every second.  Moving that line out of the function fixed the error.

The weird thing is that wasn't where Visual Studio was marking the StackOverflow error, causing much pain in attempting to resolve it.